# Notification bar disappears after showing download complete

Tags: android, android-notifications, intentservice

I am implementing a download service in which I am downloading an Image from URL. As soon as the service starts, a notification should pop up showing download in progress with progress bar. The progress bar should be updated everytime and it should show "download completed" when download is finished. However what happens is as soon as download is completed, the notification bar disappears. Also I am not able to show the progress update. I want to implement this using `IntentService`. Please help. Below is my code.

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
private String imageUrl = "http://onman.ir/colorfinder/sample.jpg";
private String folderName = "musafir downloads";
private String fileName = "sampleImage.png";
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
Notification noti;
NotificationManager manager;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private File downloadedFile;

public DownloadService() {
    super("Download Service");

}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.e("<><>", "Service started");
    createNotification("Download in progress");
    downloadedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+folderName, fileName);

    if(downloadedFile.exists())
    {
        downloadedFile.delete();
    }

    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;

    try{
        Log.e("<><>", "Inside try");
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
       /* HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try{
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                is = conn.getInputStream();
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }*/
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        Log.e("size", fileSize+"");
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);

        byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
        int incr = fileSize/100;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int count = -1;
        int progress = 0;

        while((count = is.read(data, 0, incr))!=-1)
        {
            progress += count;
            int per = (progress * 100/fileSize);
            outStream.write(data, 0, count);
            publishProgress(per);


        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outStream.toByteArray(), 0, data.length);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();

        //successfully finished
        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }finally {
        if(is!=null)
        {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(fos!=null)
        {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    publishResult("Download completed");

    Log.e("<><>", "Download finished");
}

private void publishProgress(final int per) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notification.setContentText("Download in progress");
            notification.setProgress(100, per, false);
            noti = notification.build();
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
           // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);


        }
    });
}

private void publishResult(String status) {
    if(result==Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        //notification.setProgress(0, 0, true);
        /*notification.setContentText("Download completed");*/
        /*createNotification("Download completed");*/
        notification.setContentText(status);
        notification.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        noti = notification.build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
       // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
    }
}

private void createNotification(String status) {
    Intent notifyintent = new Intent(DownloadService.this, NotificationProcessorActivity.class);

    if(downloadedFile!=null) {
        notifyintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notifyintent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(downloadedFile), "image/*");
    }
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000, notifyintent, 0);


    //Build notification
    notification = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Image Download")
            .setContentText(status).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setProgress(0,0, true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

    noti = notification.build();

    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    noti.flags |= Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH;
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The notification is getting dismissed because in your `publishResult()` function your are setting progress as `setProgress(0, 0, false)`
Try doing:

```
setProgress(100, 100, false);
```

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested. Problem still hasnt solved

Comment: the notification is still getting dismissed? Try changing false to true: setProgress(100, 100, true);